# R - Strings containing the escape character "\"

Tags: r, string, stringr, plumber

There's a few similar questions here, but none seem to provide a point of view on my particular issue.

I'm building an API with the [Plumber](https://www.rplumber.io/) package that generates sets in set notation and returns it to the browser to be displayed in [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/). MathJax is a rendering engine for LaTeX formulae.

The issue lies in creating the string in R to pass back to the browser. The render-able string in the front end reads as such

`$$\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$`

I have not been able to create that string in R because `\{` and `\}` are not valid escape sequences. Im not trying to escape them. I'm trying to put those characters in the string and pass it along. R is trying to be safe, and I need to not be safe.

R 4.0 supports raw strings with r"(...)". I upgraded to R4.0 and attempted the following:

```
library(stringr)
library(plumber)

#* @get /someFunc
someFunc <- function(){
    prefix <- r"($$\{)" 
    another <- "1, 2, 3"
    postfix < r"(\}$$)"
    result <- str_c(prefix, another, postfix)
    return(result)
}
```

Results in the following output: `$$\\{1, 2, 3\\}$$`

That string does not render correctly on the front end. The `\` is escaped, and then the `{` does not render.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to get a string that contains **only** one `\`? We are currently performing string concatenation operations on the front end, but that isn't a sustainable solution given the amount of different use-cases this API will cover in the future.

I understand that `cat` returns what I want to see, but when the string is returned to the browser by the api, the JSON object as as follows:

```
...
"content": [
  [
    "Select the correct union of the following sets"
  ],
  [
    "$$\\{20, 11, 10, 12, 19\\}$$"
  ],
  [
    "$$\\{7, 19, 5, 18, 4\\}$$"
  ]
],
...
```

Comment: `print` is your issue - it will escape things just for the printing. Use `cat` to see what's "really" there. `cat(result)` after your code gives `$$\{1, 2, 3`

Comment: no, check my edit. I'm not worried about the output of the string in R at all. I only care about what is returned to the API.

Comment: What is the code used to return the string to the browser by the API? `cat(result)` verifies that `result` contains the correct contents. You don't show any other code, so I'm not sure where else to help...

Comment: I've clarified the example again. I'm using the Plumber package as stated before. and in the clarified example, only using `return(x)`

Comment: Note that `{"value": "$$\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$"}` is not valid JSON. You can check at https://jsonlint.com/. A valid JSON string needs to have the slashes escaped as well. plumber doesn't make it easy to create invalid JSON. A proper JSON parser should have no problem returning the correct string.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick. I actually just realized that when I was looking at the JSON serializer. It appears that part of my issue was coming from my misunderstanding of proper JSON format. However, when serializing using the toJSON serializer, the output (for a single set) is `[\"$$\\\\{\",\"1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 14, 16, 17\",\"\\\\}$$\"]` There are "two" `\ ` being escaped. and the `{` is not being escaped. The issue remains it appears

Comment: I'd recommend closing your question and starting over.  I can't figure out what you did to get either the output in your comment or the final output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To identify the cause of the problem in this type of cases, I would recommend you to write assertions in your source code.

For example:

```r
library(stringr)
library(assertthat)

mathjax_set <- function(elements){
  prefix <- r"($$\{)" 
  postfix <- r"(\}$$)"
  str_c(prefix, as.character(elements), postfix)
}
cat(mathjax_set("1, 2, 3"))
#> $$\{1, 2, 3\}$$

assertthat::are_equal(mathjax_set("1, 2, 3"), r"($$\{1, 2, 3\}$$)")
#> [1] TRUE
assertthat::are_equal(mathjax_set(c(1, 2, 3)), r"($$\{1, 2, 3\}$$)")
#> [1] FALSE
```